# latest kernel killed my ThinkPad W520 hotkeys

Tags: nvidia, kernel, brightness, lenovo, thinkpad

for some reason after latest kernel/nvidia and other updates on my 12.04.5 LTS running kernel Linux ThinkPad-W520 3.13.0-43-generic #72~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 9 12:14:18 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux all my hotkeys such as volume, mute even brightness stopped working

both on my laptop and via my usb keyboard (thinkpad too) connected via USB

I tried to google and search here but couldn't find exact matching problem except [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236325/thinkpad-w520-brightness-modification-requires-suspend) which doesn't have an answer too

Comment: try updating the driver softwares of your laptop.